# Responding with custom JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a very simple task but got confused.

I need my action to respond with very simple JSON:

```
{"valid": true}
```

What do I need to write in my controller?

```
render :json => ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
render :json => { valid: true }
```

Rails should call `to_json` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
render :json => {"valid" => true}
```